# umbraco contour clientside validation not working

Tags: validation, umbraco, contour

I have Umbraco version
Umbraco v6.1.3 (Assembly version: 1.0.4954.19342)

and Contour version 3

I run MVC on the website

It is a clean umbraco install, and clean contour install

I have made a simple form, consisting of 2 inputs (2 textstrings). One of the inputs is mandatory

I can insert the form onto my razor file, and the form appears.

PROBLEM

client side validation fails

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'setDefaults' of undefined contourform.js:4
(anonymous function)contourform.js:4
(anonymous function)

Comment: It seems like jquery validate is not loaded at the right time or something.

If I comment out line 3-54 in contour.js file, and insert the plugins where all my other scripts for my website are, it works great

<script type="text/javascript"  src="/Content/js/libs/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="/Content/js/libs/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. U can See here
http://our.umbraco.org/forum/umbraco-pro/contour/45030-clientside-validation-fails-on-contour-3?p=0#comment162086

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. Seems like all the scripts aren't included by default. I added the following in Umbraco/Plugins/umbracoContour/Views/Script.cshtml

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/umbraco/plugins/umbracocontour/scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/umbraco/plugins/umbracocontour/scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/umbraco/plugins/umbracocontour/scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Above contourform.js. I'm running Umbraco 4.11 though.